# winsock recv() duplicates/missing data

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, recv

I'm writing a simple server/client program to send a file from client to server.
i'm using winsock2. I'm limiting the capacity to send the data each time to 5000.

**client side (send):**

```
int iResult = 0;
int totalBytesSent = 0;

while (length > 0){
    iResult = send( _connectSocket, data, MAX_TRANSIT_SIZE, 0 ); // MAX_TRANSIT_SIZE is 5000
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return closeSocket();
    }
    totalBytesSent += iResult;
    length -= iResult;
    //cout << "Data sent (" << iResult << " Bytes)" << endl;
}
cout << "Total Bytes Sent: (" << totalBytesSent << ")" << endl;

return 0;
```

**on the server side (recv):**

```
    // Receive and send data
char recvbuf[MAX_DATA_SIZE];

int iResult = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;

// Receive until the peer shuts down the connection

do {
    totalBytesRead += iResult;
    iResult = recv(_clientSocket, recvbuf, MAX_DATA_SIZE, 0);

    if (iResult > 0) {
        //printf("RECEIVED DATA\n");
        //printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

    } else if (iResult == 0)
        printf("Connection closing...\n");
    else {
        printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(_clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

} while (iResult > 0);

cout << "Total Bytes Received: (" << totalBytesRead << ")" << endl;
```

**The problem:**

After running client and server and sending a file, it does say the correct data size sent/received (which is of course the file size in bytes), BUT the output file is different, and when I open it with some text editor (notepad++) I can clearly see that the output file holds less data (but File->Properties shows same file sizes) and some data is duplicates.

**My Question:**

How do revc() works? If it's receiving data in many calls, does it accumulates it in the buffer? (In my case: recvbuf) or does it rewrite the buffer?
As far as I figured out, it does accumulate, so my code is correct??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

**Client side:**

```
send( _connectSocket, data, MAX_TRANSIT_SIZE, 0 );
```

- Here you never update `data` to account for the bytes already sent, so every time you call `send` it sends the same data again and again (the first `MAX_TRANSIT_SIZE` bytes of your `data` buffer). A quick fix, assuming `data` is a pointer to any byte type (uint8_t, char, ...) would be:

  `send( _connectSocket, data + totalBytesSent, MAX_TRANSIT_SIZE, 0 );`
- You should also cap the data size you send, because unless `length` is originally a multiple of `MAX_TRANSIT_SIZE` you'll have a buffer overrun when you reach the end of the data:

  `send( _connectSocket, data + totalBytesSent, std::min(length, MAX_TRANSIT_SIZE), 0 );`

---

**Server side:**

```
recv(_clientSocket, recvbuf, MAX_DATA_SIZE, 0);
```

- Just like with `send`, `recv` has no notion of "what did I already receive in that buffer". So every time you call `recv` it just put the new data it receives at the beginning of your buffer, overwriting the older data. This may or may not be what you want, this is hard to tell since you don't show us how you use that buffer. You may want to use the same approach to manage your receive buffer than the one I just explained for your send buffer.

Comment: Thanks you for your informative answer.
I will try to explain how I'm handling the transmission:
On client side: I read a file (binary stream) into char array then send it to server.

On server side: I receive the char array which represent the file from client, and write it on disk.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where you're writing out of the recvbuf.  Each time you call recv it is going to overwrite what is already in the recvbuf.  Therefore, where you have the commented out "RECEIVED DATA" prints, you should be copying the data you want to keep out of the buffer.

Comment: are you sure each time is overwrite?? because in VS2010 debugger I can see that it contains the same data (the first few bytes is a string with null ternminator so debugger displaying until the \0)

and I'm using the buffer elsewhere in the code:

fileData * fData = FileTransfer::deserializeFileData(recvbuf);

Comment: Pretty sure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx